# How to migrate from OSSpinLock to os_unfair_lock()?

Tags: objective-c, regex, macos, spinlock, regexkitlite

As of macOS 10.12, `OSSpinLock` has been deprecated. The XCode error messages urge me to use `os_unfair_lock_unlock()` instead.

As a legacy of some open source stuff I'm relying on, I'm using RegexKitLite from 2010.

How can I convert the spin lock type? Simple unlocking and locking I can manage, but these comparisons are giving me headache:

```c
if(rkl_cacheSpinLock != (OSSpinLock)0) { ... }
```

`rkl_cacheSpinLock` is of type `os_unfair_lock` and has been initialized. OSSpinLock seems to be of type `int`, so this if-statement obviously won't work.

Could anyone point me towards the right way of approaching this? I'm not too familiar with C, and don't really understand arithmetics of pointers.

**EDIT**

After learning a bit about C, I came to understood typecasting. I came up with a solution that *seems* to work. My understanding of OS functionality on this level is nonexistent. The os_unfair_lock is not too well documented for dummies, but it looks like I didn't break anything.

`if (rkl_cacheSpinLock._os_unfair_lock_opaque != 0) { ... }`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like no one ever took the time to answer your question so here goes:

```
#include <os/lock.h>

void foo() 
{
    os_unfair_lock lock = OS_UNFAIR_LOCK_INIT;
    os_unfair_lock_lock(&lock);

    /* Your critical section here */

    os_unfair_lock_unlock(&lock);
}
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/1646466-os_unfair_lock_lock) for more details on restrictions regarding where you should lock and unlock (tldr: it has to be same thread that locks and unlocks).