# 'OSSpinLock' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use os_unfair_lock() from <os/lock.h> instead

Tags: ios, swift, spinlock

I went through this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57696275/how-to-migrate-from-osspinlock-to-os-unfair-lock) but the provided solution didn't work. Can someone please explain any alternative approach or proper implementation using os_unfair_lock()?

when I am using 'OS_UNFAIR_LOCK_INIT', it seems unavailable.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use `os_unfair_lock` as below,

```
var unfairLock = os_unfair_lock_s()

os_unfair_lock_lock(&unfairLock)
os_unfair_lock_unlock(&unfairLock)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was confused with "OS_UNFAIR_LOCK_INIT"

Comment: Do not use `os_unfair_lock_s` from Swift like this.

Comment: @Rob: If `var unfairLock` is a file scope variable then it has a stable memory address, correct?

Comment: @MartinR - I have seen no formal assurances to that end. And even if it was, it seems like an implementation detail upon which I wouldn’t be inclined to depend. I’d be fascinated to better understand this. I’m going entirely upon that parenthetical reference in that video…

Comment: @Rob: It is mentioned here https://forums.swift.org/t/exposing-the-memory-locations-of-class-instance-variables/30584 and here https://forums.swift.org/t/kvo-context-param/4203/2 that top-level and static variables have a stable address.

Comment: @MartinR - Thank you for the links! It looks like they’re contemplating alternatives (though I infer that `allocate`/`initialize` is still the status quo). The idea of global/statics for locks doesn’t seem practical…

Comment: Needless to say, `OSAllocatedUnfairLock` is clearly the new status quo. Lol.

Answer (score 17):

In iOS 16 (and macOS 13) and later, you should use `OSAllocatedUnfairLock`. As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/osallocatedunfairlock) says:

> it’s unsafe to use `os_unfair_lock` from Swift because it’s a value type and, therefore, doesn’t have a stable memory address. That means when you call `os_unfair_lock_lock` or `os_unfair_lock_unlock` and pass a lock object using the `&` operator, the system may lock or unlock the wrong object.
>
> Instead, use `OSAllocatedUnfairLock`, which avoids that pitfall because it doesn’t function as a value type, despite being a structure. All copied instances of an `OSAllocatedUnfairLock` control the same underlying lock allocation.

So, if you have a counter that you want to interact with in a thread-safe manner:

```swift
import os.lock

let counter = OSAllocatedUnfairLock(initialState: 0)

...

counter.withLock { value in
    value += 1
}

...

counter.withLock { value in
    print(value)
}
```

For support of earlier OS versions, see my original answer below.

---

In [Concurrent Programming With GCD in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/?time=1085), they warn us that we cannot use `os_unfair_lock` directly in Swift because “Swift assumes that anything that is `struct` can be moved, and that doesn't work with a mutex or with a lock.”

In that video, the speaker suggests that if you must use `os_unfair_lock`, that you put this in an Objective-C class (which won't move the `struct`). Or if you look at some of the [stdlib code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/88b093e9d77d6201935a2c2fb13f27d961836777/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Publishers%2BLocking.swift#L18), they show you can stay in Swift, but use a `UnsafeMutablePointer` instead of the `struct` directly. (Thanks to bscothern for [confirming this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61529580/1271826).)

So, for example, you can write an `UnfairLock` class that avoids this problem:

```swift
final class UnfairLock: NSLocking {
    private let unfairLock: UnsafeMutablePointer<os_unfair_lock> = {
        let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<os_unfair_lock>.allocate(capacity: 1)
        pointer.initialize(to: os_unfair_lock())
        return pointer
    }()

    deinit {
        unfairLock.deinitialize(count: 1)
        unfairLock.deallocate()
    }

    func lock() {
        os_unfair_lock_lock(unfairLock)
    }

    func tryLock() -> Bool {
        os_unfair_lock_trylock(unfairLock)
    }

    func unlock() {
        os_unfair_lock_unlock(unfairLock)
    }
}
```

Then you can do things like:

```swift
let lock = UnfairLock()
```

And then use `lock` and `unlock` like you would with `NSLock`, but using the more efficient `os_unfair_lock` behind the scenes:

```swift
lock.lock()
// critical section here
lock.unlock()
```

And because this `UnfairLock` conforms to `NSLocking`, you can use extensions designed for that. E.g., there is a very useful Foundation extension [`withLock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocking/4059821-withlock/) for the `NSLocking` protocol. This is a useful way of ensuring that locks and unlocks are properly scoped/balanced, thereby avoiding the brittleness of the above `lock`/`unlock` pattern. You can do things like:

```swift
lock.withLock {
    // critical section here
}
```

That will `lock` before the “critical section” runs, and `unlock` when complete, ensuring that everything is properly balanced, even if you have some “early exits” inside the critical section.

But, going back to the original question, never use `os_unfair_lock` from Swift without something like the above or as contemplated in that [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/?time=1085), both of which provide a stable memory address for the lock.