# Can we use C struct based API directly from Swift?

Tags: c, swift, struct

I walked away from WWDC 2016 with the understanding that we should be wary about using C-based `struct` API directly from Swift. In [Concurrent Programming With GCD in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/?time=1085), talking about C-based locks, they were very specific:

> ... And in Swift, since you have the entire Darwin module at your disposition, you will actually see the `struct` based traditional C locks. However, Swift assumes that anything that is `struct` can be moved, and that doesn't work with a mutex or with a lock. So we really discourage you from using these kind of locks from Swift. ...
>
> ... And if you want something ... that looks like the locks that you have in C, then you have to call into Objective-C and introduce a base class in Objective-C that has your lock as an ivar.
>
> And then you will expose `lock` and `unlock` methods, and a `tryLock` if you need it as well, that you will be able to call from Swift when you will subclass this class. ...
>
> ```
> @implementation LockableObject {
>     os_unfair_lock _lock;
> }
>
> - (void)lock   { os_unfair_lock_lock(&_lock); }
> - (void)unlock { os_unfair_lock_unlock(&_lock); }
> @end
> ```

However, watching WWDC 2019 [Developing a Great Profiling Experience](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/414/?time=1009), I notice that the author is using `os_unfair_lock` directly from Swift, without this Objective-C wrapper, effectively:

```
private var workItemsLock = os_unfair_lock()

func subWorkItem(...) {
    ...
    os_unfair_lock_lock(&self.workItemsLock)
    ...
    os_unfair_lock_unlock(&self.workItemsLock)
    ...
}
```

Empirically, this sort of direct use of `os_unfair_lock` appears to work, but that doesn’t mean anything. Respecting the caveat in the 2016 WWDC video, I have refrained from using `os_unfair_lock` directly from Swift.

So, the question is, are they being (ever so slightly) sloppy in the use of this API in this 2019 sample? Or was the 2016 video incorrect in its claims? Or has the handling of C-based `struct` changed since Swift 3, now rendering this pattern safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API example of using `private var workItemsLock = os_unfair_lock()` can fail at runtime.

The threading primitives from C need a stable memory location so to use them or another struct that has one of these primitives directly as a member of it you have to use `UnsafePointer`. The reason for this is that `UnsafePointer` APIs once they have allocated a chunk of memory that memory is stable and cannot be moved or trivially be copied by the compiler.

If you change the example like this it is now valid

```swift
private var workItemsLock: UnsafeMutablePointer<os_unfair_lock> = {
    // Note, somewhere else this will need to be deallocated
    var pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<os_unfair_lock>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    pointer.initialize(to: os_unfair_lock())
    return pointer
}()

func subWorkItem(...) {
    ...
    os_unfair_lock_lock(self.workItemsLock)
    ...
    os_unfair_lock_unlock(self.workItemsLock)
    ...
}
```

Comment: This `allocate` pattern is precisely what Apple has [done within stdlib](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/88b093e9d77d6201935a2c2fb13f27d961836777/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Publishers%2BLocking.swift#L18). I’m concluding that the WWDC 2019 #414 code snippet was just a bit sloppy, and that the underlying concerns outlined in that WWDC 2016 presentation still apply. Thanks.